# EditText crash when empty

Tags: java, android, android-studio

so I have an EditText field,and when the user tap a number,its start counting down.
The problem starts when the are not entering a number the app crash.

this is what I tried to do:

Thanks for the help.

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mEnterNumber;
    TextView mTest;
    int timerIsRunning = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void StartRemainder(View view){
    
        mTest = findViewById(R.id.mTest);
        mEnterNumber = findViewById(R.id.mEnterNumber);
    
        int userNumb = Integer.parseInt(mEnterNumber.getText().toString()) * 60000;
    
    
        if(userNumb < 0 || mEnterNumber.toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter correct number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
    
        CountDownTimer userTimer = new CountDownTimer(userNumb,1000) {
    
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    
                long millis = millisUntilFinished;
    
                //Convert milliseconds into hour,minute and seconds
                String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
                mTest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mTest.setText(hms);
                timerIsRunning = 1;
    
            }
    
    
    
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
    
    
            }
        }.start();
        }
    
    }
```

----------------------This is the error I get when the app crash:--------------------------------

```
2020-09-04 04:09:15.024 27096-27096/com.example.drinkme E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.drinkme, PID: 27096
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:620)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
    at com.example.drinkme.MainActivity.StartRemainder(MainActivity.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

line of error:

```
int userNumb = Integer.parseInt(mEnterNumber.getText().toString()) * 60000;
```

Comment: Hey Dor, can I see the full stacktrace?

Comment: @FelixFavourChinemerem thanks for replay,do you mean the full code?

Comment: Nope, I mean the piece of code that shows you what went wrong with your code. It is usually visible in the `Run` or `Debug` tab of your Android Studio below.

Comment: Sure,I am editing my post.

Comment: try including a try-catch block for the exception: `NumberFormatException` for this line, `int userNumb = Integer.parseInt(mEnterNumber.getText().toString()) * 60000;`

Comment: because you are putting a null/empty value on an equation, so it produces a syntax error as a calculator do, So instead you need to capture the null value and convert it to zero or any value you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is with this line:

```
int userNumb = Integer.parseInt(mEnterNumber.getText().toString()) * 60000;
```

And it is because, an empty string(`""`) cannot be converted to a number unlike strings like `"1"` or `"2"`

**To fix this:**
We Provide a **try-catch** block for the `NumberFormatException`

```
int userNumb = 0;
try {
    if (mEnterNumber != null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mEnterNumber.getText().toString())) {
        userNumb = Integer.parseInt(mEnterNumber.getText().toString()) * 60000; 
    }
} 
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting the text from the edittext before checking weather  it's empty or not. Try this :

```
if(userNumb < 0 && mEnterNumber.`getText()`.toString().isEmpty()){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter correct number", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int userNumb = Integer.parseInt(mEnterNumber.getText().toString()) * 60000;
}
```

As you can see  I've put the integer conversion in the if block as it might also be the reason for it.

Comment: I get it now,Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Felix Favour said it's because you're trying to parse a non-numeric item into a string. This line:

```
mEnterNumber = findViewById(R.id.mEnterNumber);
```

Will most likely resolve to Null if nothing is entered. You can try setting it to a numeric value:

```
    mEnterNumber = findViewById(R.id.mEnterNumber);
    if mEnterNumber.getText().toString().equals("")
    {
        int userNumb = 0;  // or whatever value you want to set as a starting default
    }
    else
    {
        int userNumb = Integer.parseInt(mEnterNumber.getText().toString()) * 60000;
    }
```

This invariably could need more improvement for checking or preventing other non-numeric entries ofcourse.

Alternatively, you can also set it in the XML like this:

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/mEnterNumber"
    ...
    android:text="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this -

```
if (mEnterNumber.getText().toString().matches("")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter any number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
```

I hope this will prevent the crash.